# wordpress query from multiple post id

Tags: wp-query

I am getting array of post id from custom metabox.I tried

```
            $urls= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'videos', false );
             foreach ( $urls as $url ) {
               foreach ( $url['link'] as $u ) { 
                 $posts[] = $u;
                     }
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'slider', 'post__in' => $posts ) );

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
   while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();
        the_title();
   }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

This loop query the selected post ids but they are not in id order.They are in default ASC order.Other approach that I have tried

```
$a=explode(" ",$u);
//$posts[]=$u;
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'slider', 'post__in' => $a ) );
```

This shows only last post in the array.On var dump

```
string(2) "67" string(2) "77" //$u
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example also needs the `orderby` parameter set, otherwise it defaults to standard date order:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'slider',
        'post__in' => $posts,
        'orderby' => 'post__in'
    )
);
```

Comment: Thx a lot.Saved my life